# How to refract the name of a variable within one class only

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a question that could save myself and many others many hours of time. Is there a way that I can use refractor in android studio to change the name of a variable in one class only? I understand that is confusing, but I am recycling a lot of code between my classes, so where as a `textView` in one activity may be named `txt1`and I copy and paste it into a new activity, it needs to become `txt2`, so instead of doing this for a couple thousand lines of code, is there a way I can change `txt1` within the SECOND CLASS ONLY to `txt2` automatically? Thank everyone!

Comment: Thanks for the up vote did it work out for you? If not maybe others can help.

Comment: @Pomagranite I haven't done any research. I upvoted your post because I actually hadn't thought of plugins yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this issue I used the `find and replace` function within NotePad++. It may not be the only way to do it, but it was very simple and quick.

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler than you think. Do the following:

1. Right click on any variable/class/method you want to rename.
2. Choose `Refactor` -> `Rename`

or select any thing you want to rename and hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Now you can rename easily.

Comment: Won't that will change the name of the variable/class/method in the entire application? Which is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: The class/method will be renamed everywhere they are used. Global variables will be renamed everywhere but and local will be renamed locally.

Comment: Okay thank you, my way just so happened to be quicker in this case. By that is because I have to change hundreds of variables for each class. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: `find and replace` is ONLY quicker than `refactor` when where is **only one** occurrence of the string to be replaced; which is mostly not the case. Hence `refactor` is always the quicker than `find and replace`.

Comment: Glad you know my situation better than I do. I'm also glad that NotePad++ has find and replace all option. Really helpful :D

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the text (single class in your case) and use `Replace`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am going to let you do the work on this. Plugins are available for Android Studio/intelij click file settings plugins go [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=androidstudio&category_id=89) and pick one of the editors of your choice. You may have to go to file settings tools and set the new editor as default. Most IDE's have plugins you can use for odd jobs. One example is making parcelable from a bean. Maybe others can tell you how to do your task without a plugin but definitely something you could look into.